# csv.writerow appears to be failing to write rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv, disk

I have a script that writes close to 800,000 rows to various CSV files.

```py
for col in data:
        with open('output/{}.csv'.format(col), mode, encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator = '\n')
            if mode == 'w':
                writer.writerow(headers)
            for row in data[col]:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

On modern machines this appears to function correctly and write all rows.

However on older machines (Using mechanical hard drives) there is around 35% to 40% rows missing in total.

**Here is a list of the machine, and the total rows written (out of 815143):**

- Macbook pro osx 10.15(16gb ram, SSD) - 815143
- Windows 10 (32gb ram, NVme) - 815143
- Windows 10 (4gb ram, HDD) - 543737
- Windows 10 (4gb ram, HDD) - 501335

Is there something I am doing incorrectly that is causing this?

Or are write failures something to consider? when using `csv.write`?

Comment: If Python isn't raising any exceptions then I would suggest running whatever disk-checking utilities that are available for Windows 10.

Comment: This is unlikely to be something to do with your disks, and more likely to be your accounting (how are you counting the rows?) or your input data (it may not always be the same)!

Comment: @ti7 I'm using `wc -l output/*` (This contains all of the csv files) I presume that `wc` is accurate

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the cause of this issue is Python's output buffer.

https://blog.finxter.com/what-is-python-output-buffering-and-how-to-disable-it/

passing the `-u` flag when running python appears to fix the issue of csv rows not being written on *slower* machines.

Eg:

```
python -u file.py argument
```

Hopefully this helps anybody else who encounters the same issue.